# NestJS + Lambda + Express not able to make it work for graphql subscriptions

Tags: lambda, graphql, nestjs, serverless

I have a setup where I use @nestjs/graphql with serverless lambda deployment and the server with express adapter.
I have a similar setup as https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/multiple-servers.

The problem I am facing is that when I send a subscriptions via serverless it doesnt process.

According to the documentation at the end it says : This recipe does not work with GraphQL Subscriptions.

Is there a way to get subscriptions working?